# How to make a gradient color change based on distance from the primary object?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes

I'm trying to recreate the boost effect from Rocket league specifically the 'purple flamethrower.' Im having issues keeping the color changed based on the distance from the car. I found a method to almost get the effect that I want but the color change doesn't stay static and falls back too far.

[image: But through the animation the gradient begins to slip and doesnt maintain a fixed position from the car.]

[image: The remixed node setup from Devise's blender pack.]

Comment: may i ask why you didn't add a multiply/divide node after the separate xyz?

Comment: I just did thanks, also I should say the issue is the gradient slowly starts all pink then goes all blue instead of staying 1/3 blue and 2/3 pink the entire time.

Comment: if you provide your blend file, i will take a look - honestly, i am too lazy to rebuild it manually

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=GqNbbVLG" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GqNbbVLG/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean an effect like this? (sorry, i wasn't sure about the effect you want to achieve)

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks, that was what I wanted to do.